# When two elements use transform to move at the same time, why there is a gap in the middle?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, frontend

Here is my bug demo:
https://jsbin.com/gijabuseca/edit?html,css,js,output

[bug img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8GJG.png)

Is it a browser bug?

I solved this problem by replacing `transform: translateX (100%)` with `left: 100%`

However, using left to change the position performance is much lower than transform. If insist on using transform, is there a way to solve this gap problem?

Comment: I can't see any problem in the demo ...

Comment: @vals  you can see my bug img, bug only appears when two elements is moving

Comment: In my PC, and firefox, everything is ok

Comment: @vals  I found this bug on the chrome...and I just tested it on the edge,edge is ok,so it is a bug for chrome?

Comment: Yes it, is a bug in Chrome.  I find it hard to make it disappear, though

Comment: @vals  I tested it on safari too, and it works ok,maybe it only appears on chrome

Answer (score 0):

A hack around this bug can be changing slightly the movement of div 1.

Offsetting a litle bit the timing function from what the standard **ease** value is, we adjust it closer to div2.

I have set the transition slower so that it is easier to see if it fails

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector('.demo1').classList.add('right'); 
  document.querySelector('.demo2').classList.add('right');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.demo1, .demo2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  transition: 4s;
}

.demo1 {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.23, 0.12, .25, 1.05);
}
 
.demo2 {
  transform: translateX(100%);
 }

.demo1.right {
  transform: translateX(100%)
 }

.demo2.right {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="demo1"></div>
  <div class="demo2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank your answer, i have already found a way to fix it, i move the parent element 'wrapper',so there is no gap..